# Finding length of array pointer - Valgrind error : Invalid read size of 1

Tags: c, arrays, valgrind

```
void OneDToTwoD(char* rel){

  /*  all the declarations here */

  while(rel[i] != '\0'){
    i++;
  }

...
```

In the code above, I am getting all "sometimes" a segmentation fault. and valgrind check throws "Invalid read of size 1" at me at the line 
 `while(rel[i] != '\0'){`

In that line, I'm trying to figure out the length of `rel`. 
 I know there must be  a better way to do this. I can't just do `sizeof` can I?

Comment: I assume i starts at 0? (not shown in your code and C doesn't do nice defaults). Why not use `strlen()`?

Comment: There are quite a few things missing from this code that could cause problems. How big is the array rel? You should pass the array size in to `OneDToTwoD`, because there is no guarantee internally to the function that it's null-terminated. Where does i start? Is it initialised to 0?

Comment: Are all `rel` the function `OneDToTwoD` called with terminate with `'\0'`?

Comment: if some `rel` doesnt terminate '\0' it would cause an infinite loop wouldnt it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `i` is initialized as zero, and `rel` is pointed to valid memory block, this will work well.

1. `rel` is pointed to invalid memory block or NULL.
2. rel is not terminated with `\0`
3. `i` is not started with 0.

And one more answer, you can't know the size of memory block from pointer. pointer is not memory block. pointer can specify invalid memory block if you want. So if you want to know the length of memory block, add the `length` argument to the function.

Comment: Actually, `rel` is `malloc` properly before it's passed. `i` does start with zero.

Comment: say if `rel` doesnt terminate with \0 . How do I go about finding the length of the array.

Comment: @stackplasm look the following part of my answer. you can't do it.

Comment: BTW, If the `rel` is string, you can use strlen() insted of your function.